# AWS plugin to create a CloudFormation stack if it doesn't exist

Tags: python, python-2.x, error-handling, amazon-web-services

The following Python class is what I am trying to refactor in the case where I have to add validation of the existence of an AWS cloudformation stack before creating it in the method **create_cfn_stack** :

```
import boto3
import botocore
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

class AWSPlugin(object):
    """ AWS Plugin class """
    def __init__(**kwargs):
        """ setting kwargs to class object variables"""
        pass

    def get_stack_info(self, stack_name):
        """ returns the cloudformation stack details """
        client_response = None
        try:
            cfn_client = self.get_client(AWS_SERVICES.CLOUDFORMATION)
            response = cfn_client.describe_stacks(StackName=stack_name)
            client_response = response['Stacks'].pop()
        except ClientError as ce:
            self.log.error("Failed to retrieve cloudformation stack object : %s", ce)
        except Exception as e:
            self.log.exception("Exception occurred while retrieving cloudformation stack object : %s", e)
        return client_response

    def create_cfn_stack(self, stack_name, cfn_template_file, parameters):
        """ creates a cloudformation stack """
        client_response = None
        try:
            with open(cfn_template_file, 'r') as jfp:
                template_body = jfp.read()
            cfn_client = self.get_client(AWS_SERVICES.CLOUDFORMATION)
            cfn_response = cfn_client.create_stack(
                            StackName=stack_name,
                            TemplateBody=template_body,
                            Parameters=parameters,
                            DisableRollback=False,
                            Tags=[
                                {
                                    'Key': 'Name',
                                    'Value': stack_name
                                },
                            ]
                        )
            client_response = cfn_response['StackId']
        except ClientError as ce:
            self.log.error("Failed to create cloudformation stack : %s", ce)
        except Exception as e:
            self.log.exception("Exception occurred while creating cloudformation stack : %s", e)
        return client_response
```

There are 3 ways the code can could be refactored as shown here :

**Way 1:**

```
def create_cfn_stack(self, stack_name, cfn_template_file, parameters):
    """ creates a cloudformation stack """
    client_response = None
    try:
        existing_stack = self.get_stack_info(stack_name)
        if existing_stack is not None:
            raise Exception("Stack %s is already exists and in %s state" %(stack_name, existing_stack['Status']))
    except ClientError as ce:
        print "Stack is not present and its good to create with name %s" % (stack_name)
        with open(cfn_template_file, 'r') as jfp:
            template_body = jfp.read()
        cfn_client = self.get_client(AWS_SERVICES.CLOUDFORMATION)
        cfn_response = cfn_client.create_stack(
                        StackName=stack_name,
                        TemplateBody=template_body,
                        Parameters=parameters,
                        DisableRollback=False,
                        Tags=[
                            {
                                'Key': 'Name',
                                'Value': stack_name
                            },
                        ]
                    )
        client_response = response['StackId']
    except Exception as e:
        self.log.exception("Exception occurred while creating cloudformation stack : %s", e)
    return client_response
```

**Way 2**

```
def create_cfn_stack(self, stack_name, cfn_template_file, parameters):
    """ creates a cloudformation stack """
    client_response = None
    try:
        try:
            existing_stack = self.get_stack_info(stack_name)
            if existing_stack is not None:
                raise Exception("Stack %s is already exists and in %s state" %(stack_name, existing_stack['Status']))
        except ClientError as ce:
            print "Stack is not present and its good to create with name %s" % (stack_name) 
        with open(cfn_template_file, 'r') as jfp:
            template_body = jfp.read()
        cfn_client = self.get_client(AWS_SERVICES.CLOUDFORMATION)
        cfn_response = cfn_client.create_stack(
                        StackName=stack_name,
                        TemplateBody=template_body,
                        Parameters=parameters,
                        DisableRollback=False,
                        Tags=[
                            {
                                'Key': 'Name',
                                'Value': stack_name
                            },
                        ]
                    )
        client_response = cfn_response['StackId']
    except ClientError as ce:
        self.log.error("Failed to create cloudformation stack : %s", ce)
    except Exception as e:
        self.log.exception("Exception occurred while creating cloudformation stack : %s", e)
    return client_response
```

**Way 3**

```
def create_cfn_stack(self, stack_name, cfn_template_file, parameters):
    """ creates a cloudformation stack """
    client_response = None
    try:
        existing_stack = self.get_stack_info(stack_name)
        if existing_stack is not None:
            raise Exception("Stack %s is already exists and in %s state" %(stack_name, existing_stack['Status']))
    except ClientError as ce:
        print "Stack is not present and its good to create with name %s" % (stack_name)

    try:
        with open(cfn_template_file, 'r') as jfp:
            template_body = jfp.read()
        cfn_client = self.get_client(AWS_SERVICES.CLOUDFORMATION)
        cfn_response = cfn_client.create_stack(
                        StackName=stack_name,
                        TemplateBody=template_body,
                        Parameters=parameters,
                        DisableRollback=False,
                        Tags=[
                            {
                                'Key': 'Name',
                                'Value': stack_name
                            },
                        ]
                    )
        client_response = cfn_response['StackId']
    except ClientError as ce:
        self.log.error("Failed to create cloudformation stack : %s", ce)
    except Exception as e:
        self.log.exception("Exception occurred while creating cloudformation stack : %s", e)
    return client_response
```

Among 3 or apart from what I have shared here, I am not sure what is the standardized way to handle such a scenario. Helping hands are very much appreciated.

Comment: I don't get it. Why do you expect to get a `ClientError` when calling `self.get_stack_info(stack_name)`? It's already handled in there.

Comment: I am using AWS python SDK called `boto3`. If any AWS related exceptions/errors caught, then it ll falls under `ClientError`. 
In this scenario, I wanted to create an AWS resource in the specified name which should not exist when I call this method. To validate that, I called another method called `get_stack_info()` which returns detailed info about stack if exists else it'll throw ClientError. I have to react to both the situation and act accordingly.

Comment: Except the `ClientError` is caught in `get_stack_info` and never get a chance to bubble up to `create_cfn_stack` (which makes the first solution broken, ihmo).

Comment: Please include the relevant `import` statements for clarity.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger, I agree with you. But the challenge here is, I have to avert the blast would be created by the **get_stack_info** method and proceed to create a new resource in the case of no resource with a given name is present.